# \perp and \parallel with equal height

Tags: math-mode

I'm looking for a way to get symbols for perpendicular and parallel with an equal height. I want to use the symbols as a superscript to a function like

```
\Psi^{\perp/\parallel}
```

However, it looks kind of awkward since the two symbols are not displayed at the same height (the parallel sign is way larger). If I use

```
\scriptstyle\parallel
```

the symbols have approximately the same height but are not aligned properly in the vertical direction.

---

**Update:** I found out that

```
\Psi^{\perp/\raisebox{0.5pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle\parallel$}}(x)
```

produces what I'm looking for. Still this is kind of a hack and more consistent solution would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you construct a symbol using vertical rules.  One version that will adapt itself to different math modes is

```
\newcommand{\myparallel}{{\mkern3mu\vphantom{\perp}\vrule depth 0pt\mkern2mu\vrule depth 0pt\mkern3mu}}
```

which you can use as

```
\Psi^{\perp/\myparallel}
```

The height of the `\vrule` here automatically adjusts to the height of `\perp`, setting the depth to `0pt` makes it fit with the base of that symbol too.

Comment: Woohh, nice one. Thanks a lot. :) By the way, I think it looks a bit better with \mkern1mu in the middle.

Comment: Different fonts will require different choices of the spacing parameters before, after and between the rules.  Please feel free to adjust as necessary.